# error on python assignment on lower and upper bounds

Tags: python

i cant seem to figure out what the error is asking me to change. I tried changing the 1.0 in the lower bounds to 0.1 but it still gave me the same error. i took this screenshot before the edit I made, but I don't know what to change. can someone help please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOQEt.png)

changed 1.0 ot 0.1 and the same error popped up again

Comment: Neither 1.0 nor 0.1 is a valid lower bound when the upper bound is zero!

Comment: so what should i change in my code then?

Comment: @armanimiller The second value in your `ub` list is currently `0.0`, therefore, the second value in the `lb` list must be *less* than `0.0`, OR fix the upper bound to be greater than 1.0